# Moving vertices with different transition delays using an uniform variable

Tags: three.js, glsl

I want to morph the vertices from one 3D model to the next with three.js, using different durations and delays for individual vertices.

First of all, I load both of my models, take the model with bigger vert count and copy it's vertices positions. Then, I take the second model and assign it's vertices positions as a `targetPosition` attribute:

```
class CustomGeometry extends THREE.BufferGeometry {
   constructor (refGeo1, refGeo2) {
      super()
      let count = refGeo1.attributes.position.count

      let targets = new Float32Array(count * 3)
      for (let i = 0; i < count; i += 3) {
        // if there is no corresponding vertex, simply assign 0
        targets[i + 0] = refGeo2.attributes.position.array[i + 0] || 0
        targets[i + 1] = refGeo2.attributes.position.array[i + 1] || 0
        targets[i + 2] = refGeo2.attributes.position.array[i + 2] || 0
      }

      this.addAttribute('position', refGeo1.attributes.position)
      this.addAttribute('targetPosition', new THREE.BufferAttribute(targets, 3))
   }
}
```

Then I can pass an uniform variable `mixFactor` and do this in my vertex shaders:

`vec3 newPosition = mix(position, targetPosition, mixFactor)`

And here is an live [example](https://codepen.io/gbnikolov/pen/JyXKaW)

This works fine, except the vertices move uniformly through space (with same timing durations) when the mixFactor variable is changed. How does one add delay and different timings to the mix?

I understand I can do `attribute float mixFactor` insted of uniform and then tween all of them on the CPU, but this will kill my performance... I suspect I have to add `transitionTiming` and `transitionDelay` float attributes to my vertices, but am lost how to do the math in my shaders...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add yet another attribute for each vertex, maybe call it `mixAmountOffset`. Use that in your mixAmount calculation in the shader.

```
attribute float mixAmountOffset;
uniform float mixAmount;

....

    float realMixAmount = clamp(mixAmount + mixAmountOffset, 0., 1.);
```

Then use `realMixmount` in you mix

```
vec4 position = mix(position1, position2, realMixAmount);
```

You only have to update `mixAmount` in JavaScript

to try to be clearer you need `realMixAmount` to pass between 0 and 1 for every vertex. So let's say you set `mixAmountOffset` to negative values from 0 to -1 for vertex

```
for (let i = 0; i < vertexCount ++i) {
   mixAmountOffset[i] = -i / vertexCount;
}
```

now the math for `mixAmount + mixAmountOffset` needs to pass all points from 0 to 1. The range for `mixAmountOffset` is now 0 to -1 which means when mixAmount is 0 `mixAmount + mixAmountOffset` will go from 0 to -1 across all vertices. Because of the `clamp` that will be 0 to 0 across all vertices.

When `mixAmount` is `1` then `mixAmount + mixAmountOffset` will go from 1 to 0. Meaning only the first vertex is using the second model's positions, the last vertex is still using the first model's position.

You need to lerp `mixAmount` from 0 to 2. That way when `mixAmount` is 2 then `mixAmount + mixAmountOffset` will go from 2 to 1 across all vertices and the clamp will make that 1 to 1 across all vertices. In other words all vertices will be using model2

What `mixAmountOffsets` you use and how to do the math to compute a `realMixeAmount` is really up to you. The point is you need to make the math so before things start all vertices get a  `realMixAmount` of 0 and after things end all vertices get a `realMixAmount` of 1. There are an infinite number of ways to do that.

Looking at your code you were passing in the vertex index for `mixAmountOffset` so for example you could pass yet another uniform `vertexCount` and do `scaledMixAmountOffset = mixAmountOffset / vertexCount`.

Or, you could put positive values from 0 to 1 in the `mixAmountOffset` buffer and lerp `mixAmount` from -1 to 1.

Or ... etc ...

Other things you might want to do:

Of course you can use some kind of smoothing function on `mixAmount` when you lerp but in this case since every vertex is effectively lerping separately you probably want to put the smoothing function inside the shader

Example:

```
 ... 

 float smooth(float pos) {
    pos *= 2.;
    if (pos < 1.) {
      return 0.5 * pow(2., 10. * (pos - 1.));
    }
    return 0.5 * (-pow(2., -10. * --pos) + 2.);
  }

  void main () {
    float realFactorOffset = clamp(mixFactor + mixFactorOffset, 0.0, 1.0);
    realFactorOffset = smooth(realFactorOffset);
    vec3 newPosition = mix(position, targetPosition, realFactorOffset);


 ...
```

see: https://codepen.io/greggman/pen/aymqdV

Comment: hey @gman, thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work. It ends up displaying second model just fine while the first model's positions end up in some weird undefined space. you can check it out here: https://codepen.io/gbnikolov/pen/JyXKaW

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize I needed to spell everything out.  Updated answer to try to make it clearer

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354515/users-fake-editing-questions-to-gain-reputation-and-question-editor-status